# Should passing the application context to so many classes in the application be avoided?

Tags: android

I know sending activity context as argument to classes is a bad practice,
But I have an application in which so many application context are being passed to so many classes, I'm worried about it and want to know is it a bad practice or not ?

BTW, I don't use static variable in the mentioned classes to store the passes application context but to make the context global for all parts of a class, I normally define a global context

> Context mGlobalContext

and then use

> this.mGlobalContext = c

where c is the argument of the passed context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [blog](http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) by **Romain Guy** as in summary he said keeping activity context can cause memory leaks but if the context shared between classes is application context then the memory leak can be avoided.So sending `application context` will not cause you memory leak as per **Romain Guy**. :D

In my view and what i practice is, i pass context only if needed and context scope(lifecycle of Activity/Application) need's to be kept in mind before sending the context to different activity.